# How to simplify the expression $m+n \cdot 2m - mn + 3n \cdot 4m -2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$m+n \cdot 2m - mn + 3n \cdot 4m -2$$

I'm in grade nine and my exams are coming up and I'm struggling to learn all the things i need to, I have more of a grasp on the more advance concepts but the simple ones I keep forgetting, help?

Comment: This is most certainly not regular expressions :)

Comment: Do you mean $m+N\times 2m-mn+3n\times 4m -2$?

Comment: Sorry yeah I just had to pick a tag because it wouldn't let me post, and yeah that's what I meant

Comment: Hint: $\;3n \cdot 4 m=12 mn\,$. Repeat, then collect.

Answer (score 3):

For an expression like $$3n\times 4m$$ you can simplify this my remembering that for multiplication, it doesn't matter what order you do it in. i.e. $1\times2=2\times 1$, so $$3\times n\times 4\times m=3\times 4\times m\times n$$
Then you can reduce this by calculating $3\times 4=12$, and omitting the $\times$ signs. $$12mn$$

Similarly, $$n\times 2m=2\times m\times n=2mn$$

---

So now your expression is $$m+2mn-mn+12mn-2$$ You should notice that there are a lot of terms with $mn$ in them. These can also be simplified - you have $2$ lots of $mn$, then take one away and then add $12$, leaving a total of $2-1+12$ lots of $mn$, which is $13mn$ - (we did this by factoring out the $mn$ and thus getting $(2-1+12)mn$).

So now your expression is $$m+13mn-2$$ Now no terms can be simplified further since they are all different - they have nothing which can be factored out as we did for $mn$ above. So this is the final answer.